# SAXParseException code cvc-elt.1 for given xsd/ xml

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, moxy

I have a given xsd file and given examples for this file. the xsd is very similar to http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/hospitalinvoicerequest_400.xsd but with one additional element below the root.

The problem is if i validate the given xml against the schema (using moxy as JAXBCOntextFactory) i got this error:

```
enterCaused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 221; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'invoice:request'.
```

invoice:request is the root element the xml begins:

```
<invoice:request role="production" xmlns:invoice="http://www.medidata.ch/QO/XSD" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.medidata.ch/QO/XSD QO_MDInvoiceRequest_400.xsd">
```

If i validate the xml against the schema [online](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html) or in eclipse (right click validate) all works fine. And if i change the name space from

```
xmlns:invoice="http://www.medidata.ch/QO/XSD"
```

to

```
xmlns:invoice="http://www.xmlData.ch/xmlInvoice/XSD"
```

the error disappears - but i get another one because of the additional element. 
With this name space declaration i can't even read the contents without validation: the getter for root returns null. With the alternative declaration ("http://www.xmlData.ch/xmlInvoice/XSD") and without validation all works fine!

So whats wrong with the name space declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that your document is not valid because there is no definition for an element with local name `request` and namespace prefix `invoice`. Your instance document has a namespace binding for that prefix and schema location hint for the same namespace URI, so that part seems to be correct.

Check your schema for the following problems:

1. Is the target namespace of the schema the same as the one used by the root element of your document (here `http://www.medidata.ch/QO/XSD`)
2. Is there a global element declaration for an element with the same local name as your root element (here `request`)
3. If the your root element is declared in the schema with a namespace prefix, is that prefix bound to same namespace URI that is used in your document

If any of these is incorrect, your document is invalid. (There might also be other problems later on in your schema or in the instance XML document that makes it invalid.)

Usually (if your XML document **really** is valid) such problem is caused by either one of these two reasons:

1. your schema document is not found
2. the element name is misinterpreted because the parser is not set to be namespace aware

The markup `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.medidata.ch/QO/XSD QO_MDInvoiceRequest_400.xsd"` defines that the schema for elements in namespace `http://www.medidata.ch/QO/XSD` is found from the relative (file) location `QO_MDInvoiceRequest_400.xsd`. So if you don't specifically tell the parser what schema document it should use, it will look for a file with that name from the same folder where the input document is.

For the second reason I can't give any good help since I'm not familiar with moxy but/and I am in the assumption that moxy always handles XML files as namespace aware.

Comment: I am relatively sure that "the parser is not set to be namespace aware" because the xml validates fine as i stated above - online ane in eclipse (if i put the xsd in same folder as xml). On the other hand i just tried my test: it works with validation turned off now (no null element anymore) but validation still fails with same error. So thank you for pushing me in right direction.